# Google prettify not showing colors

Tags: javascript, css

I cant seem to find whats wrong. I have this html file used with google prettify. Both prettify.css and  prettify.js are in the same directory as the html file

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="prettify.js"></script>
<link rel=StyleSheet href="prettify.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<pre class="prettyprint">
//Some sample text
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
    //Do something
}
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what it looks like

[image: screenshot]

What am I missing to have the colors showing?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `onload="prettyPrint()"` to your document's body tag.

```
<body onload="prettyPrint()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that will do the proper syntax highlighting

```
<html>
<head>
 <!--<script src="prettify.js"></script>I commented out your links-->
 <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
 <!--<link rel=StyleSheet href="prettify.css" type="text/css"> I commented out your links-->
</head>

<body>
 <pre class="prettyprint">
   //Some sample text
   for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
     //Do something
   }
 </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

[See the code live here](https://codepen.io/tanyagupta/pen/ZajQda)